# How to iterate through an array of objects with checking the key of iteratees with the state?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Variable br must consist only of **bool values**. Which have been gotten by looping through the first array.

```
state ={
    nonRelated: this.props.non_related.value,
    1:true,
    2:true,
    3:false,
    4:false,
    5:true,
   //  etc.
}

let ar = [1,2,3,4,5,6,....20];
let br = ar.map(el => {
return state.el
})
```

**Another example:**
[image: practical example]

**I need to filter the array, if the key in the iteratee (which is an object) in the state has the value "true".**

Comment: `state[el]` not `state.el`. Also `.forEach()` doesn't pay attention to the return value of the callback function. You probably want `.filter()`.

Comment: I think you meant `map` not `forEach`

Comment: Yes, but it doesn't make much difference :)

Comment: @Pointy yes, in my actual code it's .filter(), which is in the photo.